# Magento2 add custom logic to shopping cart rule using Observers

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

How can I add custom logic using observers when cart rules apply in checkout?

I want to apply buy 3 of x,y,z get 2 of a,b free and discount. Is it possible in cart rules?

Comment: Please update question with what logic you are trying to applying. What's running in your mind.

Comment: Buy 3(x,y,z) get 2(a,b) free and discount. Is it possible in cart rules?